# Solving Second-Order Non-Homogeneous Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given equation:

$$y''-y = 4\sinh(x)$$

My first step is to simplify the left hand side ($y''-y$) into $r^2-1=0$

Then is it right that $r= \pm 1i$ and we use homogeneous equation $y_h=c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)$ to solve the equation?

Comment: $r^2-1=0$ has real roots $1$ and $-1$ and not imaginary roots

Comment: @Fakemistake then we use homogeneous equation $y_h=c_1e^{r_1x}+c_2e^{r_2x}$?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine! So $r_1=1$ and $r_2=-1$.

Comment: @Fakemistake I thought that the particular solution would be $y_p=Asinhx+Bcoshx$ but this way it cancels out. For $sinhx$ isn't the particular solution as mentioned before?

Comment: $\lbrace e^x,e^{-x}\rbrace$  and $\lbrace \cosh(x),\sinh(x)\rbrace$ are two fundamental sets of sulution. You can work with the first or the second. For a particular solution, you have to try $axe^{x}+bxe^{-x}$ or $ax\cosh(x)+bx\sinh(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Homogeneous part is:

$$y_h=C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x}$$

The right side of equation is actually of the same form:

$$C_3\sinh x=\frac{C_3}2(e^x-e^{-x})=C_4e^x+C_5e^{-x}$$

...so your particular solution should be:

$$y_p=Axe^x+Bxe^{-x}\tag{1}$$

This is equivalent to:

$$y_p=Dx\sinh x+Ex\cosh\tag{2}x$$

You can use either (1) or (2) to find the particular solution.

Comment: how did you know that $C_3sinhx=\frac{C_3}{2}(e^{x}+e^{-x})$

Comment: $\sinh x=\frac 12 (e^x-e^{-x})$ by definition.

Comment: do you get final equation as $y=e^{x}+e^{-x}+2xcoshx$

Comment: Your solution is not of the form (1) or (2)